# EmberJS 2 route dynamic segment in not nested routes undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Really new to ember and trying to setup basic (in my mind) routes.

I have `calendars` resource and I want to display individual calendars.

My `app/router.js` has the following:

```
this.route('calendar', {path: 'calendars/:calendar_id'}, function () {
    this.route('show');
    this.route('edit');
});
this.route('calendars', function(){
    this.route('create');
});
```

Folders are as following:

```
app/routes: [
  calendars: [create, index],
  calendar: [edit, show]
]
app/templates: [
  calendars: [create, index]
  calendar: [edit, show]
]
```

In `app/routes/calendar/show.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(params) {
        return this.store.findRecord('calendar', params.calendar_id);
    }
});
```

Problems start when I go to http://SERVER/calendars/5/show (5 is a :calendar_id part, SERVER is what hosts ember app) :

- when I log **params** - they are undefined
- In dev tools I see that Ember somehow makes a POST request to my server as http://SERVER/calendars/5
  (a **:calendar_id** part, SERVER is on same domain and where my back-end resides).
- This happens regardless if I comment out `model()` function in `app/routes/calendar/show.js` file.
- Apparently Ember knows what **calendar_id** to use for that request.
- But I don't know where that call to the server happens:

  - If I comment out `model(){}` altogether, my template renders model record (the calendar record that Ember fetches).
  - If I on the other hand try to log **params** in `model()` and I comment out `this.store.findRecord` part out, the **params** are undefined and it raises an error.
- I thought at first that it is my DS.RESTAdapter since I have defined updateRecord changes to fake PUT request (my server does not allow that), but I commented out the whole file and it still does this query.
- I've cleaned both **dist/**, **tmp/**, upgraded to 2.9.0, but it does the same thing.
- I have no **controllers** defined

How does Ember make POST request if model() hook is missing from route, I have no controllers difined. Also how do I fix it so that it works? ;p

**Edit [2]**:

I am trying this now and I think it kinda works, but looks ugly:

```
this.route('calendars',{ path: '/calendars'}, function(){
    this.route('create');
});
this.route('calendar', { path: '/' }, function () {
    this.route('show', { path: '/calendars/:calendar_id/show' });
    this.route('edit', { path: '/calendars/:calendar_id/edit' });
});
this.route('index', { path: ''});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ember is smart enough to generate a default route if you do not create one, and a default model if you do not create a model function.

It does this based on the routes name ie if your route is "calendar" it generates a model function based on the "calendar" model.

Try explicitly define your route path with the parameters as per ember docs:
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/routing/defining-your-routes/

```
this.route('calendar', function () {
    this.route('show', { path: '/:calendar_id/show' });
    this.route('edit', { path: '/:calendar_id/edit' });
    this.route('create');
});
```

Comment: I see. I however already have `app/models/calendar.js` model defined. I did not define any controller however. Trying this setup looks for `/calendars/:calendar_id/:calendar_id/show` route being set up. Removing `/:calendar_id` from it brings me back to the same problem.

Comment: To clarify it generated the model function in the route NOT the model itself

Comment: I edited the sample to remove the path from the parent route so they are now only in the nested routes

Comment: Yea, this way it works, it makes a route like `/calendar/:calendar_id/show`. But I wanted to have it like `/calendars/:calendar_id/show` and `/calendars/create` without nesting these routes. I don't know if I am deviating from a certain convention but I wanted to keep it consistent under `/calendars` because in my mind it would show all calendars on that page.

Comment: Either way is fine I would suggest nesting because it allows you to have a "base" calendar route and template which fits more with the SPA ideology. I re-edited to include the create in a more terse manner